# SyntaxError: /root/anon/config.json: Unexpected token ]

Tags: json, syntax-error

The full error is:

```
SyntaxError: /root/anon/config.json: Unexpected token ]
at Object.parse (native)
at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:425:27)
at Module.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at loadJson (/root/anon/anon.coffee:63:3)
at getConfig (/root/anon/anon.coffee:51:12)
at main (/root/anon/anon.coffee:136:12)
at Object.<anonymous> (/root/anon/anon.coffee:147:3)
at Object.<anonymous> (/root/anon/anon.coffee:3:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
at Object.exports.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:173:23)
at compileScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:224:29)
at compilePath (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:174:14)
at Object.exports.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:98:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee:7:41)
at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
at startup (node.js:136:18)
at node.js:966:3
```

The code I'm working with is:
https://pastebin.com/pVYwHpLc
(Don't worry, I changed the keys.)

I'm confused what and where the error is (front end is my thing). Any help is appreciated.

Sorry to bother.

Comment: can you post the config.json file?

Comment: Yup, just posted.

Comment: The config.json file is not a valid json. You need to remove the comma on line 12 after "204.97.104.30".

Answer (score 0):

Although a bit late answer, the error is on line 12:

```
"204.97.104.30",
```

You should delete the comma character (,) to have a valid JSON